# Fréchet barycenter on circle

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(x_i)$ be $n$ points a the circle. Let 
$F(x)=\sum_i d(x,x_i)^2$
be a function on the circle. When it exists, let 
$B(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\operatorname{argmin}(F)$.
$B$ is called the Fréchet barycenter. When things are well defined, is the Fréchet barycenter associative? I can't find a counter example.